# Palo Alto Router Webserver-log removal

Tags: router, firewall, palo-alto

What is the CLI syntax to remove webserver-logs from a Palo Alto router?

Comment: A bit more detail should be offered up.  Software version number, what you've tried already, hardware platform if relevant.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. From the PAN-OS CLI Reference Guide:

> The following command lists the contents of the web server error log.
>
> username@hostname> less webserver-log error.log
>
> webserver-log — Lists contents of the specified webserver log file (press tab for a list of log files)

The CLI Reference Guide mentions the `clear` command but it does not apply to the web-server logs.

From this Palo Alto support page, the `delete` command can be used to delete specific files.

Source: [Palo Alto - delete command](https://live.paloaltonetworks.com/docs/DOC-4687)

I would suggest trying `delete ?` to see the full context of the delete command.